# Windows 10 IoT Core ARM64 AppServiceConnection for background apps debugging

Tags: debugging, uwp, arm64, windows-10-iot-core

We have a number of apps written in C#, some headed some non-headed (background). They are able to communicate with each other via Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService.AppServiceConnection, which works rather good on ARM on e.g. a Raspberry Pi 3 B (which works well enough with Windows 10 IoT Core, no hardware rendering tho which is a bummer). We are *not* using Native Tool chain when building our apps for ARM. As building them with Native Tool chain takes forever, so we would like to avoid it if possible.

For non-headed (background) apps built for ARM64 running on Windows 10 IoT Core Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService.AppServiceConnection seems to not work while *debugging*, when we try to connect to a app service we are greeted with AppServiceConnectionStatus.AppUnavailable. Which means:

```
//     The package for the app service to which a connection was attempted is temporarily
//     unavailable. Try to connect again later.
```

Even when we try to connect later the app fails to do so. A foreground app succeeds to connect, after a while, after a number of tries.

In practice this makes it almost impossible for us to debug (and therefore develop) our apps for ARM64.

To summeries debugging on ARM64 *works* but Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService.AppServiceConnection does *not* work as expected when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the remote tools with the same architecture as the machine you're installing them on. Please see the detail info about [Remote Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019).
If you use Visual Studio 2019, you can download the Remote Tool for Visual Studio 2019 that the version matches your ARM64 device in [this page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).
[image]

Comment: I'm able to debug but as soon as I do Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService.AppServiceConnection doesn't work as expected. Especially for non-headed apps.

Comment: Have you tried to test the connection when in release?

Comment: @FinitelyFailed, have you tried to download and use the remote tool in above mention?I doubt it is due to the remote debugging tool.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2017 as I found 2019 works quite badly with ARM64. To be honest using Visual Studio, C# on ARM64 works not that great, feels like everything is in alpha or similar.

Comment: You may post this issue via Feedback Hub App to improve the experience on Visual Studio.